# Where do I put the contents of the source folder with the b9 aerospace pack?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

I've downloaded the B9 Aerospace Pack, and I've put everything where it needs to go, except for the contents of the folder named source. Where do I put the contents of this folder in my KSP directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That folder isn't required for the mod to run.  It contains the source code for some of the plugins that B9 uses, specifically Kine Tech Animation, ResGen, and Virgin Kalactic.

Many plugin developers release the source code for their plugin along with the actual plugin, usually under an open source license like LGPL.  If another mod maker wants to use such a plugin, they may be required, through the terms of the license, to also release the source code with their plugin (although most of the time you're only required to release *changes* to the source, and include a link to the original).

In the end, the source folder serves a few purposes:

- Giving credit where credit is due
- Following the terms of the license
- Sharing information in the spirit of free and open software

and has no impact on the people who just want to use the mod.